# Confidential token transfer whitepaper

Tags: token-2022

I recently watched the talk "Use Token-2022 for Everything". The speaker mentions that there is an interesting whitepaper about the system they are implementing. Where can I find this whitepaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper can be found in the solana program library under the token program folder.

Direct link:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/zk-token-protocol-paper

Note: This tech requires transaction size increases that have yet to roll out. Additionally, the confidential transfer code and paper have not yet been audited. You can follow the progress on the official discord under the #spl channel.